# Inline resin identification codes (recycling codes)?

Tags: symbols, lyx

I would like to use [resin identification codes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Resin_identification_codes) (the [recycle triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes) arrows + identifier inside) inline, as part of my text. How can I achieve this? LyX-oriented answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps you can follow for obtaining a vectorized version of an image:

1. Download an SVG version. Let's assume you download [this file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Resin_identification_codes#/media/File:Plastic-recyc-01.svg):

   [image]
2. Convert it to PDF using something like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).
3. In LyX, Insert > Graphics... and identify the PDF you want to insert:

   [image]

   I've changed the LaTeX and LyX options to be `height=.7\baselineskip`. You can choose whatever you want here. This will insert the image into your document and visually appear like this in LyX:

   [image]
4. Now Document > View Output (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) displays

   [image]

<sub>Step 2 is optional, as LyX 1.6.6+ provides automated conversion support for SVG images if Inkscape is already installed on your machine ([source](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UseInkscapeSVGImages)).</sub>

Comment: Why convert to PDF if svg is supported?

Comment: @Sparkler: True, provided that you have Inkscape installed already. I've added a reference to that effect at the end of my post. SVG images are not supported natively by LaTeX.

Comment: Your solution is totally workable, although I expected there is a neater solution.